# Changing addresses faster than a parallel SRAM's response time

Tags: sram

(Parallel) SRAM data sheets often list response times such as 70ns.

If /CE and /RD are held low, and the address is changed every 35ns, what will be the output on the data pins?

I am expecting either the contents of those address (delayed by 70ns) or a complex mess dependent on the row/columns of the addresses.

i.e. Is the response time a uniform delay, or a maximum upper bound on a non-uniform delay.

Comment: Simple SRAMs are not pipelined. Not respecting the access time spec will produce unpredictable results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> data sheets list 70 ns ... changed every 35ns

When you violate a spec, all other promises made by the vendor become null and void.

You have to assume that you get garbage out, and most likely that is exactly what will happen.

The minimum and maximum specs are named that for a reason.